# Compiler optimization on loop independent variables

Tags: optimization, fortran, compiler-optimization

I have a Fortran program. The pseudo code as follows:

```
do x=1,nx
  do y=1,ny
    do z=1,nz
      function(x,y,z)
    end do
  end do
end do

function(x,y,z)
  if(var==1)
    ! do something
  else if(var==2)
    ! do something else
  end if
end
```

Here the variable `var` is read from input-file at the beginning of program and does not change during the course of execution. I read that a `if` check is deep inside `for/do` loops, it can break down performance by ignoring "cache effects". Since the variable does not change over course, can the compiler reorder the code such that the benefits of cache effect can be seen?

If this is not the case, how to avoid the `if` check or better ways to implement such a scenario?

Comment: As it stands, I'd probably call this question "too broad".  Two answers both saying the complete opposite are probably valid: there's just too much left to our imagination here.  For example, you say `var` doesn't change, but is it a named constant or does it even have the `volatile` attribute?  Whether your compiler can work things out depends on the compiler (and if it can, whether it does, depends on compile flags) and how the code is laid out.  And the benefit may depend on your architecture and branch prediction.  And so on.  I suggest you write your own complete example and profile it.

Comment: The variable `var` is not defined constant. But read from an input-file. And the scope of `var` is unmodified throughout the program.

Answer (score 0):

```
do x=1,nx
  do y=1,ny
    if (var == 1)
      do z=1,nz
        function1(x,y,z)
      end do
    else if (var == 2)
      do z=1,nz
        function2(x,y,z)
      end do
    endif
  end do
end do
```

Comment: I know this would be the logical solution. But the `function` by itself is very long and does many other features. The `if` check is only a small component of the `function`. Therefore, writing two functions would unnecessarily increase the code length. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @SathishKrishnan If the function is very long, there is no point willing to avoid the `if`, this is a useless microoptimization.